# python twitter Api() not found error

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to use the python-twitter module, but still having problems initiating the twitter.Api(). I've checked and rechecked that no other file named twitter.py or twitter.pyc is on my system. On a clean install i first try to

```
>>> import twitter
```

and correctly get a response of 'module unknown'

I do a `easy_install twitter`, successfull.

Then do

```
>>> import twitter
>>> testapi = twitter.Api()
```

The response is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    testapi = twitter.Api()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
>>>
```

I'm exhausted trying to locate the problem here, please help.

Comment: Hi Perdo and welcome to SO. In future, please use the `{}` option to format your code.

Comment: Also, the response `module unknown` is not a successful response. If the `import` worked, you should get no response. `module unknown` means it is not working.

Comment: @sukhbir: the response `module unknown` at the top *is* correct.  The OP is demonstrating that there is no `twitter` module on his system at that point.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that you are trying to follow the documentation for one Python Twitter module when you are in fact using another Python Twitter module.

The `Api()` method call you mention is part of [this Python Twitter module](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/).  However, when you use `easy_install twitter`, you actually get [this other Python Twitter module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter).